# Syntax error on swagger-jsdoc setup in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-jsdocs

I am getting a syntax error on trying to set up swagger with my express app

I was trying to follow this tutorial here https://itnext.io/setting-up-swagger-in-a-node-js-application-d3c4d7aa56d4 as a quick start guide, I do not know why I am getting that error

This is my app.js

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import swaggerUI from 'swagger-ui-express';
import swaggerJSDocs from 'swagger-jsdoc';
import allRoutes from './routes';


const definitions = {
  info: {
    // API information (required)
    title: 'Wayfarer', // Title (required)
    version: '1.0.0', // Version (required)
  },
  securityDefinitions: {
    bearerAuth: {
      type: 'apiKey',
      name: 'Authorization',
      scheme: 'bearer',
      in: 'header',
    },
  },
};

const options = {
  definitions,
  apis: ['./routes/index.js'],
};

const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDocs(options);

const app = express();

app.get('/swagger.json', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(swaggerSpec);
});
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(swaggerSpec));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

allRoutes(app);

export default app;
```

And here are my routes in `./routes/index.js`

```
import userRouter from './users';
import busRouter from './buses';
import tripRouter from './trips';

const versionNumber = '/api/v1';

export default (app) => {
  app.use(versionNumber, userRouter);
  app.use(versionNumber, busRouter);
  app.use(versionNumber, tripRouter);
};
```

And one of the routes eg `./routes/users`

```
import router from './router';
import userMiddleware from '../middleware/users';

router.post('/auth/signup', userMiddleware.signupClients(), userController.signUp.bind(userController));

router.post('/auth/signin', userMiddleware.signinClients(), userController.signinClients.bind(userController));

router.post('/auth/signin/admin', userMiddleware.signinAdmin(), userController.signinAdmin.bind(userController));

export default router;
```

I followed the instructions and my app should work instead I am getting a `Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at module.exports (/home/frank/Desktop/Web Dev/Git projects/Way-Farer/node_modules/swagger-jsdoc/lib/index.js:32:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/frank/Desktop/Web Dev/Git projects/Way-Farer/api/src/app.js:32:21)` error

Comment: 1) What line is line 32 in app.js? 2) Possibly unrelated, but you need to remove `scheme: 'bearer'` from `securityDefinitions` in app.js. This is an OpenAPI 3.0 keyword whereas your API definition syntax appears to be OpenAPI 2.0.

Comment: line 32 in app.js is `const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDocs(options);` . Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: Removing `scheme: 'bearer'` did not solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In app.js, change `definitions` (plural) to `definition` (singular). swagger-jsdoc [expects](https://github.com/Surnet/swagger-jsdoc/blob/master/docs/GETTING-STARTED.md) that the option containing the API definition be named either `options.swaggerDefinition` or `options.definition`.

```
const definition = {  // <-----
  ...
};

const options = {
  definition,      // <-----
  apis: ['./routes/index.js'],
};
```

Comment: Wow, this finally worked, never crossed my mind it was just down to a specific variable/property. Can start comment/documenting my API, thanks again